# Spring Integration TcpNetServerConnectionFactory for Single Never Close TCP Connection

Tags: spring-integration

Does the below ensure a **never close single** `TCP connection`, as well **recover from any network errors** by closing and recreating the `TCP connection`? Our use-case is legacy and requires a single TCP connection that should keep on reading and writing. Kindly suggest.

Also, couldn't find a way to include / configure `heartbeat` messages in the `IntegrationFlow` DSL.

```
    @Bean
    public AbstractConnectionFactory tcpNetServerConnectionFactory() {
    
        var tcpNetServerConnectionFactory = new TcpNetServerConnectionFactory(port);
        tcpNetServerConnectionFactory.setLeaveOpen(true);
        tcpNetServerConnectionFactory.setSoTimeout(-1);
        tcpNetServerConnectionFactory.setSoKeepAlive(true);
        tcpNetServerConnectionFactory.setSoTcpNoDelay(true);
        tcpNetServerConnectionFactory.setSerializer(byteArrayLengthHeaderSerializer());
        tcpNetServerConnectionFactory.setDeserializer(byteArrayLengthHeaderSerializer());
    
        return tcpNetServerConnectionFactory;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but the recovery is done by the client creating a new connection, not the server.

Comment: Thanks, we simulated connection drop at client end and framework recreated new connections in those scenarios.

Comment: W.r.t a `TcpNetClientConnectionFactory` heartbeat messages, should it just be a scheduler using the same `TcpNetClientConnectionFactory` and nothing more to hook into the actual application flow? Thanks

Comment: You could use TCP keep alives rather than application level heartbeats; it depends on how you are using the client factory; if it is for an outbound gateway, you must use that same gateway for the heartbeats, you can't hook multiple gateways to the same factory.